# Solution for Schrödinger equation for constant box potential?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, potential

It is known that in a box potential, when we set $V  = 0$ inside and $V = \infty$ on the boundaries, the solution to the equation $$ - \frac{\hbar}{2m} \bigg( \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{ \partial^2}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2} \bigg) \psi(x,y,z) = E \psi(x,y,z) $$ is given by $$ \psi_{n_x, n_y, n_z} (x,y,z) = C \sin( \frac{n_x \pi x}{L}) \sin (\frac{n_y \pi y}{L}) \sin(\frac{n_z \pi z}{L}). $$ Here $L$ is the dimension of the box. The energies are $E_n = \frac{\hbar^2 \pi^2 }{2mL^2} n^2 $ with $n^2 = n_x^2 + n_y^2 + n_z^2$. Now, I was wondering, what if the potential inside the box is not zero, but we let it be $V = V_0$, a constant? What is the solution of the Schrödinger equation then? And what are the energy eigenvalues?

Does this amount to adding a phase factor to the solution (the product of sines)?

Comment: Still the same. Only that $E_n = \frac{\hbar^2n^2\pi^2} {2mL^2} + V_0$

Comment: I see. But how did you deduce that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equation will become
$$ - \frac{\hbar}{2m} \bigg( \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{ \partial^2}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2} \bigg) \psi(x,y,z) = (E-V_0) \psi(x,y,z) $$
And the solutions are the same:
$$ \psi_{n_x, n_y, n_z} (x,y,z) = C \sin( \frac{n_x \pi x}{L}) \sin (\frac{n_y \pi y}{L}) \sin(\frac{n_z \pi z}{L}). $$
And Energy:
$$(E_n - V_0) = \frac{\hbar^2\pi^2} {2mL^2}n^2$$
$$E_n = \frac{\hbar^2\pi^2} {2mL^2}n^2 + V_0$$

Path to the solution:

By separation of variables:
$$\frac{1}{X}\frac{d^2X}{dx^2} + \frac{1}{Y}\frac{d^2Y}{dy^2} + \frac{1}{Z}\frac{d^2Z}{dz^2} = -\frac{2m}{\hbar^2}(E-V_0)$$
$$\frac{d^2X}{dx^2} = -k_x^2X;   \frac{d^2Y}{dy^2} = -k_y^2Y;   \frac{d^2Z}{dz^2} = -k_z^2Z$$
with 
$$(E_n - V_0) = \frac{\hbar^2} {2m}(k_x^2 + k_y^2 + k_z^2)$$
Solution:

$X(x) = A_x\sin k_xx + B_x\cos k_xx$ and so on.

as usual, $B = 0$ because $X(0) = 0$ because of infinite potential at boundaries.

also, $X(L) = 0$ (infinite potential) means $\sin k_xL = 0$ or

$k_x = n_x\pi/L$ and so with the others. 

So still the same:
$$ \psi_{n_x, n_y, n_z} (x,y,z) = A_xA_yA_z \sin( \frac{n_x \pi x}{L}) \sin (\frac{n_y \pi y}{L}) \sin(\frac{n_z \pi z}{L}). $$
$$ \psi_{n_x, n_y, n_z} (x,y,z) = C \sin( \frac{n_x \pi x}{L}) \sin (\frac{n_y \pi y}{L}) \sin(\frac{n_z \pi z}{L}). $$
$$(E_n - V_0) = \frac{\hbar^2\pi^2} {2mL^2}(n_x^2+n_y^2 + n_z^2)$$

Comment: This is because $V_0$ is a constant

Comment: Very nice little derivation. +10.

Comment: I got this from solution manual (Griffiths) :) but without the $V_0$.